# Unable to make view equal width to cell in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, custom-cell, uitableview

I am making a custom cell in iOS.I have added prototype cell.I m trying to add a view inside a cell of equal width to parent cell.But the width of cell is not equal please tell me how  should i do it?

[image]

**Constraints are:**

[image]

**View structure:**

[image]

**EDIT:**

In preview on iPad it does not show complete view
.But on actual device it works fine.Why?

**sample here**

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7RGQm8-8k24Q0tXUFZOLUZFQk0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you try set width of `contentView` of your `customCell`?

Comment: show your constrtaints if you are adding any

Comment: Please see the constraints

Comment: @TechGuy you are not puttin any constraints on width? Equal width constraint will come in handy in your situation

Comment: Also don't forget to make sure that your tableview is center aligned horizontally and cell width is equal to tableview's width

Comment: I am giving leading trailing 0 so that it expand to full view .I have tried the equal width but it does not work

Comment: Please explain what the orange view on your screenshots is, add more details about the cell views structure (preferably add a screenshot of fully expanded cell views tree). Right now it isn't clear what view is the Superview you are aligning your view to, neither what are it's constraints.

Comment: Yellow is background color of the cell here & great color is table view background

Comment: Is any body there?I am looking for solution

Comment: why did you add aspect ratio constraint for content view?

Comment: I removed the aspect ratio but still it does not work.

Comment: I have already made it

Comment: NO .i AM STILL HAVING ISSUE

Comment: see the issue is in the preview the width does not expand but on real device sit shows fine why?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7RGQm8-8k24Q0tXUFZOLUZFQk0/view?usp=sharing 
check here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I checked your sample project I found that You made your viewController size to `iPhone4.7 inch`...and I checked the source code of storyboard and I found that `targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch"`

So, at the time of preview,it just copied the reference for preview which is basically iPhone size and display you the iPhone size preview...

For the solution what I do is...just change in Storyboard source code..

Search for  `targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch"`  and change it to `targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad"` and then just check preview...and you can see that it works fine....

Comment: i am using 4 inch at time of preview but it works fine for all other screens

Comment: sure .. i have another question coming in .please keep track of it.

Comment: Great answer @EICaptain

Answer (score 1):

You need to align view's (which is inside cell's content view) Leading, Trailing and Top to Cell's content view. This would be enough to make the view take the cell's width. (see screenshot)

First Screen

[image: First Screen]

[image: Second Screen]

[image]

[image]

Comment: why you have given negative values?@Manish

Comment: @TechGuy I haven't. It is the superview's margin which is auto taken when setting constraints. I disabled 'Constraints to Margin' option and then set them.

Comment: I am still not able to get the accurate result.

Answer (score 0):

You should add constraints to the view you added to the cell's content view,just like this.

[image]

Tips: It seems like the tableview don't have the correct size so the cell can't be right.You can try add the constraints to the tableview in the same way.
Hope helps.

Comment: I have added constraints in the same way but that does not woe for me.