# Auto layout in tableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I try to build an iOS app with auto layout.

I had created tableView with tableViewCell, and there are textField and button inside the cell.

I try to use constraints to make it universal, but it works only for the iPhone size, for some reason the button constraint `button.trailing equal superview.trailing Margin` not work for the iPad size , and for 1/3 iPad size

Pictures for reference
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are sure your content view is resizing properly for the iPad?

Comment: check this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036037/unable-to-make-view-equal-width-to-cell-in-ios

Comment: you right El Capitan , it's work!!! it's look like a bug in the Xcode preview engine, very strange...

Comment: ya its something in preview ... change targetRuntime works for preview ... real device its well and good as I said in that answer of that link

Comment: What if i wont to see the preview of the iPhone size and the iPad size together? without changing every time the targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch"

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should give leading,trailing,top,bottom to tableView with its superview,then give leading,trailing,top,bottom to textfield and button, give their height but constant should not be equal, height constant must be >/,in tableView delegate method you need to return height for row according to device compatibility(for iPhone and iPad).