# Width constraint doesn't work in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, autolayout, storyboard

I have spent nearly an hour on this and i don't understand why it doesn't work!!!
I am trying to add a view to my TableView cell which is the same width and height as the cell itself.

What you would normally do is to add 0 spacing to each side and it would work but It doesn't. The view stays the same size after I change my screen from iPhone 4 to iPhone 7Plus.

What I tried to do after this was to add the constraints of same height and width but same result appeared. This is really making me go crazy, any idea why it doesn't work?

Basic constraints 
[image: Before]

After changing to iPhone 7 Plus

[image: After]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036037/unable-to-make-view-equal-width-to-cell-in-ios